# oci_connect ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when using tnsnames

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface, tnsnames

I am trying to connect to an oracle database using php. When I try to connect by connection string/descriptor, it connects just fine, but when I try to connect using a tns name, the whole thing stops and chrome shows a blank error page `ERR_CONNECTION_RESER`. I see the failed response and it is 0 bytes, no header, no body... nothing.

here is the code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$connStr = "Some connection <string> copied from tnsnames.ora";
//$connStr = "Some connection <name> copied from tnsnames.ora";

try
{
    $conn = oci_connect('dev', '12345678', $connStr, 'utf8');
    if (!$conn)
    {
        $err = oci_error();
        var_dump($err);
    }
    oci_close($conn);
    echo "Success";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $err = oci_error();
    var_dump($err);
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I checked and my php can see
    ORACLE_HOME
    TNS_ADMIN
and they are pointing to the right direction.
I am using
    Windows 7 amd64
    PHP 5.6.13 TS VC11
    Apache 2.4.16 VC14
    Instant Client 12.1.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours spent and sleeps not slept on this issue, I found the solution.

I have an sqlnet.ora file that specifies timeouts and other network properties. Our databases recently joined the firm's domain and the problem was with this line:

Previously

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (HOSTNAME, TNSNAMES, ONAMES, EZCONNECT, LDAP)
#########
```

Solution

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (HOSTNAME, TNSNAMES, ONAMES, EZCONNECT, LDAP)
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = FIRM.DOMAIN
```